# R survey - twophase function and warnings with multistage designs

Tags: r, survey

I want to specify a two-phase design object with stratified three-stage sampling design using the R package `survey`. When multiple stages are passed to the `id` argument of the `twophase` function, I get the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated
```

What could be the source of this warning message?

Below is a reproducible example using [simulated data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpcatk6yqe1lcnr/simdata.RData?dl=0).

```
> library(survey)
> load('./simdata.RData')
> str(simdata)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3690 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ strat  : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ block  : int  7 7 7 7 7 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ house  : int  510 512 516 523 536 578 583 592 595 619 ...
 $ ind    : int  999 1003 1013 1026 1049 1138 1149 1167 1171 1214 ...
 $ P.block: num  0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 ...
 $ P.house: num  0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.025 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 ...
 $ P.ind  : num  0.357 0.357 0.357 0.357 0.357 ...
 $ phase2 : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ age    : num  42.7 21.5 32.2 36.9 44.1 ...
 $ bmi    : num  31.1 25.9 23.7 28.9 23.7 ...
> 
> twophase.design = twophase(id=list(~block+house+ind,~1),
+                            strata=list(~strat,NULL),
+                            probs=list(~P.block+P.house+P.ind,NULL),
+                            subset=~phase2,
+                            data=simdata,method='full')
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> 
> head(warnings())
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated
4: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated
5: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated
6: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1L) : invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Thanks!

---

**Update**:

I also got the following error message when trying `twophase` with another set of [simulated data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b9szd746dap4mlv/simdata1.RData?dl=0):

```
> load('./simdata1.RData')
> str(simdata1)
'data.frame':   3468 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ strat  : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ block  : int  4 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
 $ house  : int  435 586 587 594 613 619 619 621 634 634 ...
 $ ind    : int  854 1157 1158 1170 1203 1213 1214 1218 1242 1243 ...
 $ P.block: num  0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 ...
 $ P.house: num  0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 0.18 ...
 $ P.ind  : num  0.55 0.55 0.357 0.55 0.357 ...
 $ phase2 : logi  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ age    : num  47.8 54 38 69.4 33.2 ...
 $ bmi    : num  28 50.5 35.8 37.5 27.1 ...
> twophase.design = twophase(id=list(~block+house+ind,~1),
+                            strata=list(~strat,NULL),
+                            probs=list(~P.block+P.house+P.ind,NULL),
+                            subset=~phase2,
+                            data=simdata1,method='full')
Error in Dcheck_subset(strata[uid, stage], insubset, probs[uid, stage],  : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug.

Using

```
twophase.design = twophase(id=list(~block,~1),
strata=list(~strat,NULL), 
probs=list(~I(P.block*P.house*P.ind, NULL),
subset=~phase2, data=simdata1, method='full')
```

will give a good approximation to the intended design -- since no finite population correction is given at phase 1, the phase-1 design is treated as with-replacement sampling and only the first stage of sampling will affect the standard errors.

The fix will be in version 3.35-1 of the survey package